# How to delete a embed after a specific period

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I'm using `message.delete({timeout: 3000})` to delete messages with the prefix. How would I be able to delete the embed *I sent* after some time too?

```js
if (!args[0])
 return message.channel.send({
  embed: {
   color: 16777201,
   description: `${message.author}, You must enter a number between ** 2 ** to ** 100 ** for messages to be deleted.`,
   footer: {
    text: `   | Exemple: !clear 58`,
   },
  },
 });
```

I want the message with the prefix to be deleted after three seconds; this I already got. But, I wanted this embed to be deleted after about ten seconds as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.channel.send()` returns `Promise<Message>`, so all you have to do is create a `.then()` callback:

```js
if (!args[0])
 return message.channel
  .send({
   embed: {
    color: 16777201,
    description: `${message.author}, You must enter a number between ** 2 ** to ** 100 ** for messages to be deleted.`,
    footer: {
     text: `   | Exemple: !clear 58`,
    },
   },
  })
  .then((message) => message.delete({ timeout: 10000 }));
```